# Divide HTML to fixed height divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html

I have an HTML document and have to show it in my iPhone app's WebView.

The width of the doc is fixed, the issue is with the height. As is pretty well understood, increasing and decreasing font size in an HTML doc will only change the height of the doc, as the width is fixed.

- if font size decreases, height decreases
- if font size increases, height increases

Now, the size of the view in which I need to show the html doc is fixed say `X*Y`. So I have to divide the whole HTML doc to divs sized `X*Y`, and thus show all of them in WebView one by one more specifically saying with page curl effect.

Please suggest me how to divide the HTML doc in fixed size divs.

**Note:** the document may also contain images. In that case the image should be moved to next page if it does not fix in the current div.

Answer (score 0):

since width is fixed just get the height using jQuery

to get the height:`var heightY = $(window).height(),
    widthX=400px`

so the div would be: `$('#yourDiv').css({'height':heightY,'width':widthX});`

Comment: thanks for your answer @matthiasWegtun.. but its not the solution to my answer. the height of the frame where i need to show the html is fixed. So my aim is to divide the html in such parts where is each part fits in the frame.. please suggest how to do that.